# Help with the proof of Zorn's Lemma: if $A$ and $B$ are conforming subsets, why must it be that $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

[Here](https://digitalcommons.kennesaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2161&context=facpubs) we can find a simple proof of Zorn's Lemma, but I find something that I can't really understand. There is an statement that say: *If A and B are conforming subsets of $X$ and $A\neq B$, then one of these two sets is an initial segment of the other.*

If I take, by example, the set $X=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, I can create two conforming subsets which satisfy the definition but aren't initial segment of each other, like $B=\{0,2,4,5\}$ and $C=\{0,2,3,4\}$.

This proof is similar to another used by Gorodentsev in his book *Algebra I*, so there is a thing that I am missing here.

---

**Definition**

We shall say that a subset $A$ of $X$ is conforming if the following two conditions hold:

1. The order $\le$ is a well order of the set A.
2. For every element $x \in A$, we have $x = f(P(A, x))$, where $f$ maps the initial segment to its strict upper bound x.

**Definition**

If $C$ is a chain in $X$ and $x\in C$, then we define
$P(C, x) = \{ y \in C: y < x\}$. A subset of a chain $C$ that has the form $P(C, x)$ is called an **initial segment** in $C$.

Comment: What is $P(A,x)$, please?

Comment: I just edited the question, is a function that assigns to every chain C $\subseteq$ X, a strict upper
 bound f(C).

Comment: Given the common initial chain $\{0. 2\}$ of $B$ and $C$ the function $f$ tells you what the next element is has to be so one of $3$ or $4$ isn't allowed.

Comment: Remember that $f$ is defined on $X$, the original chain (actually in the paper it is defined on a chain $C$ taken from $X$), so returns the strictest upper bound taken from $X$. So $f(B,4)=3$, the strict upper bound of $\{0,2\}$ within $X$. Hence B is not conforming.

Comment: I just changed it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  The paper does not claim that the strict upper bound given by the function $f$ is unique ("strict" here just means that the upper bound isn't itself in the chain). The OP's example is oversimplified in making $A$ a chain rather than a more general partially ordered set.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis As far as I can get it, the definition does not say $f$ returns _the least possible_ strict upper bound: _"we can obtain an element $x \in X$ such that $y < x$ for every $y \in C$.  Such an element $x$ will be called a **strict upper bound*** of $C$."_

Comment: @RobArthan You are right. I'm getting a little confused by the paper now as it defines $P(C,x)$ only on chains C, and then uses it later on partially sorted sets $P(A,x)$. I'm not so sure what it means.

Comment: But in the OP's example we are using the totally ordered integers, so it is clear that $f(\{0,2\})$ is a single value, and that we cannot have both $f(\{0,2\}) = f(P(B,4)) =4$ and $f(\{0,2\}) = f(P(C,3)) =3$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Then at least one of $B, C$ isn't conforming.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  By condition (a) in the definition of conforming sets, conforming sets are well-ordered and hence are chains.

Answer (score 5):

No. You can't.

If $A$ is conforming, then its minimum element is $f(\varnothing)$. So that's unique, say $x_0$; then the next element is the one chosen by $f$ as an upper bound of $\{x_0\}$. So again, that's unique, call that $x_1$, etc. etc.

By transfinite induction we get that if $A$ and $B$ are both conforming, they must have been built by essentially iterating the choice function to a certain length. Since a choice function *is a function* its output are well-defined, that means that $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.

The reason you think you have two conforming subsets is that you didn't specify the choice function which maps a chain to an upper bound. Once you do, you have to ask yourself, is $f(\{x\mid x>2\})$ going to be equal to $3$ or to $4$?

Comment: The definition of a conforming set looks strange. For every $x\in A$ the initial segment defined by $x$ is taken, and then $x$ must be a strict upper bound of that segment. This implies 1. the strict upper bound is the least possible, which didn't follow from the definition; 2. the space must have a least item, which will be a strict upper bound of the empty set, so that the empty set is conforming – but the least element is not mentioned in the assumption.

Comment: No, that's not true. The upper bound is chosen by $f$. If the partial order does not have a minimum element, then $\varnothing$ does not have a "least possible upper bound".

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: BTW, did you mean $f(\{x\mid x\le 2\})$ in the last paragraph? Anyway, $f(\{0,1,2\})$ needn't equal $f(\{0,2\})$ and the example sets $A$ and $B$ would imply a contradiction on the output of the latter, not the former.

Comment: Since the order is not specified, I assume it's the natural order.

Comment: So, for the set $B$ to be conforming it needs to satisfy, among others, $4=f(P(B,4))$ $=f(\{y\in B\mid y < 4\})$ $=f(\{0,2\})$, and for $C$ it requires $3=f(\{0,1\})$. I can't see how the natural order connects $f(\{x\mid x>2\})=f(\{3,4,5,6\})$ here...

Comment: The construction of a conforming set is, essentially, by fixing a choice function and then recursively choosing an upper bound to what we previously constructed.

Comment: I undestant that. What I don't undestand is why $f(\{x\mid x>2\})=f(\{3,4,5,6\})$ has to be $3$ or $4$. The conformity requirement implies, imho, that $f(\{0,2\})$ has to be $3$ or $4$ (or both) to have the set $B$ or $C$ (or both) conforming, respectively. But how is $f(\{0,2\})$ dependent on $f(\{3,4,5,6\})$...?

Comment: Well, since the upper bounds of $\{0,2\}$ are *exactly* $\{x\mid x>2\}$. Also, $f(\{0,2\})$ cannot be *both* $3$ and $4$, just like $\sin \pi$ cannot be both $0$ and $1$ at the same time. The point is that you want whatever element comes after $2$ into your conforming subset, call it $x$, must be equal to $f(\{x\mid x>2\})$.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the error is here:

> If I take, by example, the set $X=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, I can create two conforming subsets which satisfy the definition but aren't initial segment of each other, like $B=\{0,2,4,5\}$ and $C=\{0,2,3,4\}$.

You need to define the function $f$ first, which assigns a strict upper bound to a set, and then show your set satisfies $x = f(P(B,x))$ for all $x\in B$ to say $B$ is conforming. And similarly for $C$.

That is,
$$\begin{align}
&\text{for } B & &\qquad \text{for } C \\
& f(\{\}) & = 0 & \qquad \text{same} \\
& f(\{0\}) & = 2 & \qquad \text{same} \\
& \color{red}{f(\{0,2\})} & = \color{red}4 & \qquad \color{red}{f(\{0,2\})} & = \color{red}3 \\
& f(\{0,2,4\}) & = 5 & \qquad f(\{0,2,3\}) & = 4\\
\end{align}$$

The third row shows at least one of $B, C$ can not be 'conforming'.